# What is wrong with my code? (302 error in function while signing up) + mysql database error by not saving the right login details

Tags: php

my error is in the mysql database it saves the db login instead of the user's input. also, as from the terminal(linux mint) there is a 302(temp redirect) "error" that is make some error in the code...
from the terminal is: [302]: POST /signupp.php
and all the others is [200]: GET /...
which means this is some of the error right?
now for the code itself:

index.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>hello friend</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        body {
            font: 1em sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <?php
           echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    ?>
    <h1>PHP Login System</h1>
    <?php

            if (isset($_SESSION["userme"])) {
                echo "<a href='profile.php'>Profile</a>";
                echo "<a href='logout.php'>Log Out</a>";
            }
            else {
                echo "<a href='/signup.php'>Sign Up</a>";
                echo " ";
                echo "<a href='/login.php'>Log In</a>";
            }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

db.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "phpshop";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

signup.php

```
<?php
include_once 'index.php';
?>

<h2>Sign Up</h2>
<form action="signupp.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="namee" placeholder="Full name..">
        <input type="email" name="emaill" placeholder="email..">
        <input type="text" name="userme" placeholder="username..">
        <input type="password" name="passme" placeholder="password..">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

signupp.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $name = $_POST["namee"];
    $email = $_POST["emaill"];
    $username = $_POST["userme"];
    $password = $_POST["passme"];

    require_once 'db.php';
    require_once 'functions.php';

    createUser($conn, $name, $email, $username, $password);
}
else {
    header("location: signup.php");
}
```

functions.php

```
    <?php

function createUser($conn, $namee, $emaill, $userme, $passme) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO GuestsLogs (namee, emaill, userme, passme) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo "<script>window.location.href='signup.php';</script>";
        exit();
    }

    $hashedPwd = password_hash($passme, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $namee, $emaill, $userme, $hashedPwd);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    echo "<script>window.location.href='signup.php';</script>";
    exit();
}

function loginUser($conn, $userme, $passme) {
    $passHashed = ["passme"];
    $checkPwd = password_verify($passme, "passme");

    if ($checkPwd === false) {
        echo "<script>window.location.href='signup.php';</script>";
        exit();
    }
    else if ($checkPwd === true) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["userme"] = $passme["userme"];
        echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
        exit();
    }
}
```

login.php

```
<?php
include_once 'index.php';
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <body>
            <h2>Sign In</h2>
                <form action="loginn.php" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="userme" placeholder="Username...">
                        <input type="password" name=passme placeholder="Password...">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Log In</button>
                </form>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

loginn.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $userme = $_POST["userme"];
    $passme = $_POST["passme"];

    require_once 'db.php';
    require_once 'functions.php';

    loginUser($conn, $userme, $passme);
}
else {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}
```

logout.php

```
<?php

session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();

header("location: index.php");
exit();
```

and the profile.php is empty because there is no need for it right now.

Comment: Your button doesn't have a value.

Comment: @miken32 I added but it is still not working.

Comment: @KenLee Yes and Yes. I did posted the whole code. there is no more files.

Comment: See my answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the same variable names for db login and user submitted data.

Since you required "db.php" after the user submitted $username and $password, but they are using the same variable names ($username / $password), so the data insertion will use the db credentials for data insertion.

Hence, use the following revised files:

signupp.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"]) ) {

    $namee = $_POST["namee"];
    $email = $_POST["emaill"];
    $userme = $_POST["userme"];
    $passme = $_POST["passme"];

    require_once 'db.php';
    require_once 'functions.php';

    createUser($conn, $namee, $email, $userme, $passme);
}
else {
    echo "<script>window.location.href='signup.php';</script>";
}
```

functions.php

```
<?php

function createUser($conn, $name, $email, $username, $password) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO GuestsLogs (namee, emaill, userme, passme) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){ 
    echo "<script>window.location.href='signup.php';</script>";
        exit();
    }

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $name, $email, $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    echo "<script>window.location.href='signup.php';</script>";
    exit();
}
```

signup.php

```
<?php
include_once 'index.php';
?>

<h2>Sign Up</h2>
<form action="signupp.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="namee" placeholder="Full name..">
        <input type="email" name="emaill" placeholder="email..">
        <input type="text" name="userme" placeholder="username..">
        <input type="password" name="passme" placeholder="password..">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>hi</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked! but i do still keep getting 302(temp redirect) why? and how can fix it? or it is okay to keep it like that?(which i think it needed to get fixed.)

Comment: I think it is due to your server (linux mint) setup ? Please double-check . Do  you have any special configuration or .htaccess rules in force ? (For my box I used your code but no such 302 errors).

Comment: nope. nothing special.

Comment: Thank you. but how to do that? as i cannot type js in php code as i'm getting an error.

Comment: it does not work. can you please send the whole new functions.php file code?

Comment: Hi, Please see my revised answer (with all files posted, except the db.php, which requires no changes ) - All the header location redirection replaced by javascript

Comment: thank you it is working. but can i use it without js?

Comment: now the login does not work. can you help me please? as it is keep redirecting me to the signup.php page check out the new code i have added.